# Javscript class constructor using destructuring?

Tags: javascript

I've done this before, however I like to try and stick to mainstream practices when writing so that others can read it easily enough so I thought I'd ask if it's "bad" to de structure constructors with classes?

e.g:

```js
// how you'd see a class wrote out normaly
class Task {
  constructor(label, assignedTo) {
    this.label = label;
    this.assignedTo = assignedTo;
  }
}

// with destructuring ????? 
class Task {
  constructor({label, assignedTo='unassigned'}) {
    this.label = label;
    this.assignedTo = assignedTo;
  }
}
```

But why?

Well as you can see I assigned an value to `assignedTo` so that it could be left blank and still have a value. For example if we looked at a Express JS route we could do something like...

```js
// express js API preparing data before saving to db
 
// ...

// req.body content:
// { label: 'empty dishwasher' }

// assuming the whole request body has been validated by a middleware
// pass the whole body in where req.label is an optinal field
const task = new Task({ ...req.body });

// ...
```

This way I don't have to sit there an write `req.body.xxx` or `const {label, assignedTo} = req.body;` like this this:

```js
// ...

const { label, assingedTo } = req.body;

// just an example of how I could still add a value if assingedTo is undeffined
const task = new Task(label, assingedTo ? assingedTo : 'unassinged');

// ...
```

I suppose this is "just another way" to do something however I was wondering if anyone would see this as bad practice? I personalty think it could be useful but I never see anyone doing it

Comment: It's quite a common way to effectively have named parameters, feel free to use that pattern

Comment: Why `new Task({ ...req.body })` and not just `new Task(req.body)`?

Comment: It works the same, I was just writing a quick example and had destructuring in my head, both work :) but yeah just `req.body` would have been fine

Answer (score 1):

I see two good practices here. Passing single object param with props for different param values, instead of multiple params. And setting default value for params.